# how do i configure static versioning (digest) for the asset-pipeline (bertramlabs) in my spring boot 2 application?

Tags: spring-boot, asset-pipeline

spring boot version: 2.0.4.RELEASE
asset-pipeline version: 3.0.3

Hi

we're using this plugin, because we know it from our grails applications. 
We liked it, because it has a simple configuration (for our requirements)

Now we're developing a spring boot application and we used this plugin too and we're (almost) happy with it.

But when we run the application in the development mode the assets don't have a digest like */assets/my-styles-b5d2d7380a49af2d7ca7943a9aa74f62s.css*

How do i configure the plugin to create a digest for all our resources?

currently we're using this configuration:

```
assets {
   minifyJs = true
   minifyCss = true
   enableSourceMaps = false

   includes = ["application.js", "application.scss"]
}
```

And we're using thymeleaf for our templates:

```
<link th:href="@{/assets/application.css}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution...

when you use the asset-pipeline, you get a gradle task `assetCompile`.

when creating a .war file, you can add this gradle task and replace all the assets with the versioned files.

when you want to use the versioned files in your production mode you have to use this configuration (build.gradle)

```
assets {
   minifyJs = true
   minifyCss = true
   skipNonDigests = true
   packagePlugin = true

   includes = ["application.js", "application.scss"]
}

...

war {
   dependsOn 'assetCompile'
   from( "${buildDir}/assets", {
      into "/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/assets"
   })
   baseName = '<your project>'
   enabled = true
}
```

that's all.

When running the `assetCompile` task, a `manifest.properties` file is created. This file contains the mapping of the original filename and the versioned one. 
This file is used by the application to find the correct resource, e.g. `application.css=application-79a3c8a2f085ecefadgfca3cda6fe3d12.css`

Answer (score 1):

I created a plugin which enables the url replacement for assets with digest in the production mode:

**Dependency**

```
compile 'ch.itds.taglib:asset-pipeline-thymeleaf-taglib:1.0.0'
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {
    @Bean
    public AssetDialect assetDialect() {
        return new AssetDialect();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<html xmlns:asset="https://www.itds.ch/taglib/asset">
<script asset:src="@{/assets/main.js}"></script>
</html>
```

The *asset:src="@{/assets/main.js}"* will be replaced with *src="/assets/main-DIGEST.js"*.

The replacement happens only if the developmentRuntime of the asset pipeline is disabled.

A little bit more details are available on my blog post: https://kobelnet.ch/Blog/2019/03/12/assetpipelinethymeleaftaglib